# "Member for" profile field showing wrong value

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

The "member for" field in the user profile is showing the last time visited instead of the duration of membership:

> member for    14 mins ago

Comment: I'm working on it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out you need to end your attributes in html with a quote. Who knew? If only there was a site where I could ask these things...

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_span.asp *ducks*

Comment: You can try Quora. They're the new Yahoo!Answers.

Comment: Bah, just lose the strict HTML idea.