# Bug in Member for and Got Flair?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I have two weird cases in my SO profile,

**1)** It says I am a member for **8 mins ago** (edit: right now it says I am a member for 0 secs ago, I guess you mixed the fields for member for and last seen).

**2)** Sometimes the *new* thingy appears, sometimes not, there is not a standard ratio, no matter how much times I refresh.

I am using Firefox 3.6.16 on Slackware x86_64.

Thanks. I hope question is inline with the rules.

---

[image: Member for]

[image]

Comment: Half-dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80275/member-for-profile-field-showing-wrong-value

Comment: @BalusC, oops sorry did not see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new` indicator will only show up 10% of the time now.  Marking this by-design even though there's another question in here since that one is really a dupe.